# How to create moving image likt this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

How to create moving image likt this ?

On `openload.co` you will see moving image

```
http://i.imgur.com/TJcQcpX.png
```

Then i press f12 on google chrome for check , but not found for gif image or any animate css.

I want to know how can i do image moving link this ?

Comment: it's rendered and animated with javascript into the <canvas>... It can be done with css animations and svg elements too. Possibly it's an html5 animation exported from Adobe Animate (Adobe Flash - easier for animating, than writing css animations)